# how to read property 'subscribe' of undefined?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have created a MEAN stack application which does the basic job of inserting,delete,update and viewing the data from mongoDB.
first of all i cloned this MEAN stack application from github. the application was based on the employee, but i renamed all the components, routing, etc from 'employee' to 'sensor'. what i have done literally is changed the word 'employee' to 'sensor'.
and i had not issues in compiling the code.
the build was successful.
but when i launched localhost:4200 , the first page was displayed properly,which is insert component. the data is inserted into mongodb. so this component has no issues.
but when i click on view sensor component,it shows a blank page.
so when i checked on chrome console by clicking on f12,it showed a list of errors. 
please check for the errors in the below screenshot.[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xylr.png)

the service.api code is below

```js
    
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  throwError } from 'rxjs';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {

  baseUri:string = 'http://localhost:4000/api';
  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  getSensors: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Create
  createSensor(data): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${this.baseUri}/create`;
    return this.http.post(url, data)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorMgmt)
      )
  }


  // Get Sensor
  getSensor(id): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${this.baseUri}/read/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => {
        return res || {}
      }),
      catchError(this.errorMgmt)
    )
  }

  // Update Sensor
  updateSensor(id, data): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${this.baseUri}/update/${id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, data, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError(this.errorMgmt)
    )
  }

  // Delete Sensor
  deleteSensor(id): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${this.baseUri}/delete/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError(this.errorMgmt)
    )
  }

  // Error handling
  errorMgmt(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Get client-side error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Get server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }

}
```

SENSOR-LIST.COMPONENT.TS is below

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ApiService } from './../../service/api.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-Sensor-list',
      templateUrl: './Sensor-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./Sensor-list.component.css']
    })

    export class SensorListComponent implements OnInit {

      Sensor: any = [];

      constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
        this.readSensor();
      }

      ngOnInit() {}

      readSensor() {
    this.apiService.getSensors.subscribe ((data) => {
      this.Sensor = data;
        });
      }

      removeSensor(Sensor, index) {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            this.apiService.deleteSensor(Sensor._id).subscribe((data) => {
              this.Sensor.splice(index, 1);
            }
          );
        }
      }

    }
```

some of the screenshots
img 1[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJFnC.png)

img 2[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg0ep.png)

img 3[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xylr.png)

please help me out in this problem

Comment: remove the whitespace after 'this.apiService.getSensors.subscribe'

Comment: You should replace the editor screenshot with a code block. That way others can better inspect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSensors` is not a function first of all. You declared it in `ApiService` as a variable of type any. So if you want the list of sensors. Create the `getSensors()` method which will allow you to retrieve the list of sensors via the URL intended for it

Comment: can you please specify where to create getsensors() function?

Comment: In the ApiService class

Comment: voila un exemple.
  `getSensors(): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${this.baseUri}/readAll`;
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => {
        return res || {}
      }),
      catchError(this.errorMgmt)
    )
  }`

Comment: But it will also be necessary that at the level of your backend you can have a method mapped with `/ readAll` which retrieves the list of sensors.

Comment: hello @Berthol
i have a new issue now.
is there anyway to contact with you

Comment: My gmail or whatsapp +237690735187